# PHP/Laravel How To Prevent All Functions Under One File

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7, php-7.2

There is a helper file that should not be run when the unit testing is running. What is the best way to prevent all functions from being executed when the unit test is running without having to put condition on every function in the helper?

I tried to `return false` on constructor along with `App::runningUnitTests()`, but as many of you know, the constructor in php does not return anything, therefore it does not work.

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Helper file is a class ? If so how do you register it with the app ?

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen Yes, it is a class. It's declared like `use App\Helper\ExampleHelper;`, and used in other classes.

Comment: If you are using it in other classes, won't it break if you prevent it from loading ?

Comment: No, i made sure it wont affect.

Comment: Then what's the reason to prevent it from loading ? If you can explain the story a bit more clear, it can help us resolve your issue.

Comment: The helper is for external api service which has a quota even for the development environment. So, it is okay to be executed while developing, but i want to avoid exhausting quota on unittesting